# get id from dynamic element with js

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I created a dynamic list, each element has its own id but when I have to get it from javascript with document.getElementById an error is thrown (Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')) how can I solve?

The element id are created correctly. `<li id="item1">item1</li>`

```js
//This is how I add a new element:
var counter = 1;
function addElement(){
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.innerHTML += `<li id="item${counter}">item${counter}</li>`;
}
//This function is called when the button is clicked.


//This function is called when the bottom for editing is clicked:
function changeTxt(){
    document.getElementById("changeID").innerHTML = document.getElementById("textChange").value;
}
//ChangeID is a variable saved in another function.
```

Comment: Did you use your browser inspect tool to verify if the element was created correctly?

Comment: And please try to provide a working example here in a code snippet.

Comment: It seems that your are not adding HTML, but replacing the list’s HTML for each value of counter, but to be sure you would need to provide more code.

Comment: So that means it can not find the element. My guess is we need to see more code to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you didn't quoted the ID.

I think your element look like this rn : `<li id=item64>item64</li>`

and it must look like this instead : `<li id="item64">item64</li>`

Comment: If you're right, my code below should fix it ;)

Comment: should make no difference

Comment: This makes no difference. Even for a W3C Markup validation, it does not matter. Quotes are a good practice for HTML but not necessary at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `+=` to your assignment, to not replace the list contents, but add to it. Otherwise you will only have one element in the list, which is the last counter value.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');

for (let counter = 1; counter < 4; ++counter) {

  list.innerHTML += `<li id="item${counter}">item${counter}</li>`;

}

console.log(document.getElementById("item3"));
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

If it doesn't work, use inpect tool to check if elements were created correctly ;)

Comment: Probleme may comes from ChangeID , try to print it before editing the li, and check if it has the correct value

Comment: You should not use `innerHTML` to include HTML tags as this is slow (DOM needs to be re-parsed) and poses a security risk for XSS Attack injections. instead of `list.innerHTML +=` you can add new elements to the end by using `insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content);`. besides of that, the OP already sues that.

Comment: Totally agree, that's what I do in my codes. But here, I took the code from his example to correct it ;)